# is there any way to connect amazon aws opensearch to nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-sdk-nodejs

hi am newbie in aws and don't have any idea regarding how to connect to aws opensearch service and how to put data there using node and have created a domain on opensearch but want to put some data there using node please let me know if anybody can help
please provide the answer in code format

Comment: I would start by typing "Elasticsearch Nodejs" into a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to upload data to an OpenSearch Service, using services  like Lambda, using the command line or developing your service with most programming languages.

With the OpenSearch Service you can send HTTP requests to the domain of your service, so a curl request like this one would work to you:

```
curl -XPUT -u 'master-user:master-user-password' 'domain-endpoint/movies/_doc/1' -d '{"director": "Burton, Tim", "genre": ["Comedy","Sci-Fi"], "year": 1996, "actor": ["Jack Nicholson","Pierce Brosnan","Sarah Jessica Parker"], "title": "Mars Attacks!"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

For more information about sending curl requests to OpenSearch, take a look on this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/gsgupload-data.html).

In Node.js we can do something like this:

```
var req = new AWS.HttpRequest(endpoint);

req.method = 'POST';
req.path = path.join('/', esDomain.index, esDomain.doctype);
req.region = esDomain.region;
req.headers['presigned-expires'] = false;
req.headers['Host'] = endpoint.host;
req.body = doc;

var signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(req , 'es');  // es: service code
signer.addAuthorization(creds, new Date());

var send = new AWS.NodeHttpClient();
send.handleRequest(req, null, function(httpResp) {
    var respBody = '';
    httpResp.on('data', function (chunk) {
        respBody += chunk;
    });
    httpResp.on('end', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + respBody);
        context.succeed('Lambda added document ' + doc);
    });
}, function(err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    context.fail('Lambda failed with error ' + err);
});
```

More examples can be found here: [aws-samples
/
amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples)

Comment: after following your code i am getting 400 BAD REQUEST in output